# Выбивает ошибку в OnKeyPress

Tags: delphi

Не может понять, что это такое. Мне нужно, чтобы можно было писать только цифры.

```
 procedure TForm6.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
    begin
    if key= 'a'..'z' or key= 'а'..'я' then
    begin
    edit1.Text:='';
    end;
    end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обычно массивы описываются в квадратных скобках. Из этого следует что.

```
procedure TForm6.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
    begin
    if Key in ['a'..'z'] + ['A'..'Z'] then Key := #0;

else 
edit1.Text:=edit1.Text+Key; // так вроде присвоение и работа со строками в делфях

    end;
```

И не нужно везде засовывать Begin End; если не понимаете для чего эта конструкция.

> Begin End;

нужен для того чтобы объединить блок выполнения каких то операций, выполняющихся несколько раз либо при условии if then else после then выполняется не одно действие, после else тоже может выполняться не одно действие пример.

```
if бла бла then 
    begin
     3 раза что-то делаем с переменными
    end;
   else
    просто выводим собщение
```

Answer (score 3):

Есть и второй способ:

```
const Digit:set of char= ['0'..'9'];

begin
if not (key in Digit) then
  begin
    key:=#0;
    Edit1.Text:='';
    ShowMessage('Допускается ввод только цифр.');
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот вариант, когда разрешён ввод только цифр и знака-разделителя целой и дробной части, также возможно стирание с помощью BackSpace. То же самое можно написать и через конструкцию Case.

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject;
  var Key: Char);
begin
  If Not( (Key In ['0'..'9']) Or (Key=#8) Or ((Key=DecimalSeparator)
    And (AnsiPos(DecimalSeparator, Edit1.Text)=0)
    And (Edit1.Text<>'')) ) Then
      Key:=#0;
end;
```